# How can I link paths so results are updated in dom-repeat

Tags: polymer

I am developing an appointment booking system.  It basically consists of a set of Polymer custom elements arranged as follows (indented elements are in the template of the element rather than actually organised as shown)

```
<my-appointments>
  <person-appointment booking="{{booking}}>
    <booking-type type="{{booking.type}}">
      <div>[[booking.type]]</div>
    </booking-type>
  </person-appointment>
  <appointment-day booking="{{booking}}>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{appointments}} as="{{appointment}}">
      <div>[[appointment.type]]</div>
    </template>
  </appointment-day>
</appointment>
```

inside the `<appointment-day>` element `booking` is defined as an "Object" property and `appointments` as an "Array".  As a booking is made, the booking object is spliced into the appointments array at the correct place.
At the same time I use the linkPaths function to join path 'booking' to path 'appointments.n' (where n is 0, 1, 2 etc for where in the appointments array booking is situated)

This is the code that does this

```
          if (foundAppointment) {
            //found where to insert appointment, so do so
            this.splice(path, j, 0, this.booking);
            this.linkPaths('booking', path + '.' + j);
            this.linkedBooking = true;
            break;
          }
```

Not shown is a mechanism inside `<booking-type>` to update the `type` property.  SO when I update the `type` property using this mechanism, the visual representation changes inside the `<person-appointment>` element but it does not change inside the dom-repeat.  I can check that the object located at `appointents[n]` IS updated, but the display is not updated.

I presume I haven't properly linked booking to the appropriate appointment entry.  BUT how should I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer does not observe the change of sub-properties of `appointments`.
Try to Force data system to pick up array the mutations with the code below:

```
// Force data system to pick up the **array** mutations
var array = this.appointments;
this.appointments= [];
this.appointments= array;
```

Try to add this to your code.

```
  if (foundAppointment) {
    //found where to insert appointment, so do so
    this.splice(path, j, 0, this.booking);
    this.linkPaths('booking', path + '.' + j);
    this.linkedBooking = true;
    // Force data system to pick up array mutations
    var array = this.appointments;
    this.appointments= [];
    this.appointments= array;
    break;
  }
```

Or to Force data system to pick up the **Object** mutations with the code below:

```
// Force data system to pick up array mutations
var object = this.appointment;
this.appointment= [];
this.appointment= object;
```

Comment: Although I think you might be approximately on the right lines, the dom repeat is definitely picking up changes to a sub property of the appointment array. In my real code, there is actually another copy of `<booking-type>` inside the dom-repeat, and I can update that and the appointment output updates.  In this case it is not reflected back to booking (in the display, although the value is propagated and can be seen to have been set with the debugger inside the copy of booking inside `<person-appointment>`).  I do actually play your trick on booking as I first set it up in stages (ajax calls)

Comment: I edited my initial reply, you can use the same trick for an Object mutation.

Comment: You solution isn't quite correct logically in the context of my actual code, but the appoach works.  What I actually did was put observers on the changes to appointment and booking and then used them to update the other element

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing that the problem is in [binding to array items](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#array-binding). 
Polymer has special rules for that.

Here is one example of array binding: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5jwY0t?p=preview)

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[first4People(people, people.*)]]"> 
    <div>
        Index: <span>[[index]]</span>
        <br>
        First as this:[[arrayItem(people.*, index, 'first')]]
        <br>
        First not as this: <span>[[item.first]]</span>
   </div>
   <br><br>
</template>
```

Simplified online example of the problem would help to understand the issue better.